# Re ordering Bootstrapped rows when changing screen orientation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Presently in a medium screen layout i have the following

=============================

## |   Parent    |     Child   |

## |   data      |     data    |

Now when the screen changes for mobile devices i want it like

===============

## |   Parent    |

## |   data      |

## |   Child     |

## |   data      |

How do i acheive such a thing?

Present CSS

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="myHeader">Parent</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="myHeader">Child</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    value
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    value
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any reason for downvote please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap parent-value and child-value in `col-md-6`:

```css
.myHeader {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="myHeader">Parent</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                value
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p class="myHeader">Child</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                value
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```